# convert php array into select

Tags: php, arrays, select

I have the follwoing arrray(print_r shows):

```
Array ( [address] => Array ( [0] => ikea, 17 Old Main Road, dubai ) [idDelAddress] => Array ( [0] => 102 ) )
```

I want to convert this into a select box where `[address]` is the displayed text and `[idDelAddress]` is the value to be posted with the form.

it appears they are two seperate arrays.

I have tried this but obviously it wont work fully.

```
foreach ($customeraddresses['address'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $value;
    //  echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
}
```

Thanks as always,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually your array hasn't the best structure, anyway (if i get right your structure) you can do following

```
echo '<option value="'.$customeraddresses['idDelAddress'][0].'">'.$customeraddresses['address'][0].'</option>';
```

if your array would be bigger you can do

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($customeraddresses['address']); $i++) {
    // key -> $customeraddresses['idDelAddress'][$i]
    // val -> $customeraddresses['address'][$i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well it should. Did you put a `select` tag around your `option` tags?

```
<select>
<?php

foreach ($customeraddresses['address'] as $key => $value) {

echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';

}

?>
</select>
```

You have a strange array structure. You have an array in an array which is holding only one value... The array should look like this to make sense.

```
Array ( 
    [102] => 'ikea, 17 Old Main Road, dubai '
)
```

If you can't change the structure of it, you have to do a more complicated code. Like so:

```
$countAddresses = count($customeraddresses['address']);

for($i = 0; $i < $countAddresses; ++$i) {
    echo '<option value="' . $customeraddresses['idDelAddress'][$i] . '">' . $customeraddresses['address'][$i] . '</option>';
}
```